# How to disable submit button in modal where the form is children ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, formik, yup

I have little experience in Javascript and React, I need to disable the action buttons in modal while the form is submitting, I've searched the internet and haven't found a solution.

Below is the structure of the project:

Countries list:

```
import {
  alpha,
  Button,
  makeStyles,
  Paper,
  Table,
  TableBody,
  TableCell,
  TableContainer,
  TableHead,
  TableRow
} from "@material-ui/core";
import React, { useState } from "react";

import CountryForm from "./CountryForm";
import Popup from "../../components/Popup";
import Notification from "../../components/Notification";
import * as countryService from "../../services/countryService";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  table: {
    "& thead th": {
      fontWeight: "600",
      color: theme.palette.primary.main,
      backgroundColor: alpha(theme.palette.primary.light, 0.07)
    },
    "& tbody td": {
      fontWeight: "400"
    },
    "& tbody tr:hover": {
      backgroundColor: "#fffbf2",
      cursor: "pointer"
    }
  },
  addButton: {
    marginBottom: theme.spacing(2)
  }
}));

function Countries(props) {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [openPopup, setOpenPopup] = useState(false);
  const [records, setRecords] = useState(countryService.getCountries());
  const [notify, setNotify] = useState({
    isOpen: false,
    message: "",
    type: ""
  });

  const handleClose = () => setOpenPopup(false);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Countries</h1>
      <Button
        variant="contained"
        color="primary"
        className={classes.addButton}
        onClick={() => {
          setOpenPopup(true);
        }}
      >
        Add
      </Button>
      <TableContainer component={Paper}>
        <Table
          className={classes.table}
          size="small"
          aria-label="a dense table"
        >
          <TableHead>
            <TableRow>
              <TableCell align="left">Abbreviation</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="left">Name</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="right"></TableCell>
            </TableRow>
          </TableHead>
          <TableBody>
            {records &&
              records.map((row) => (
                <TableRow key={row.id}>
                  <TableCell align="left">{row.abbreviation}</TableCell>
                  <TableCell align="left">{row.name}</TableCell>
                  <TableCell align="right"></TableCell>
                </TableRow>
              ))}
          </TableBody>
        </Table>
      </TableContainer>
      <Popup openPopup={openPopup} setOpenPopup={setOpenPopup}>
        <CountryForm
          handleClose={handleClose}
          setRecords={setRecords}
          setNotify={setNotify}
        />
      </Popup>
      <Notification notify={notify} setNotify={setNotify} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default Countries;
```

Country form:

```
import React from "react";
import { Grid, makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core";
import { Field, Form, Formik } from "formik";
import { TextField } from "formik-material-ui";
import * as Yup from "yup";

import * as countryService from "../../services/countryService";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  itemGrid: {
    marginBottom: theme.spacing(1)
  }
}));

const initialValues = {
  id: 0,
  abbreviation: "",
  name: ""
};

const validationSchema = Yup.object({
  abbreviation: Yup.string().required().min(2).max(2),
  name: Yup.string().required().max(80)
});

function CountryForm(props) {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const { handleClose, setRecords, setNotify } = props;

  function _onSubmit(fields, { setSubmitting }) {
    return fetch(countryService.insertCountry(fields))
      .then(() => {
        //setSubmitting(false);
        handleClose();
        setRecords(countryService.getCountries());
        setNotify({
          isOpen: true,
          message: `Added successfully`,
          type: "success"
        });
      })
      .cath((err) => {
        alert(err);
        //setSubmitting(false);
      });
  }

  return (
    <Formik
      enableReinitialize={true}
      initialValues={initialValues}
      validationSchema={validationSchema}
      onSubmit={_onSubmit}
    >
      {({ errors, touched, isSubmitting }) => {
        return (
          <Form id="form">
            <Grid container direction="row">
              <Grid className={classes.itemGrid} item xs={12}>
                <Field
                  name="abbreviation"
                  label="Abbreviation"
                  margin="dense"
                  variant="outlined"
                  disabled={isSubmitting}
                  component={TextField}
                />
              </Grid>
              <Grid className={classes.itemGrid} item xs={12}>
                <Field
                  name="name"
                  type="text"
                  fullWidth
                  label="Name"
                  margin="dense"
                  variant="outlined"
                  disabled={isSubmitting}
                  component={TextField}
                />
              </Grid>
            </Grid>
          </Form>
        );
      }}
    </Formik>
  );
}

export default CountryForm;
```

Modal:

```
import React from "react";
import {
  Dialog,
  DialogTitle,
  DialogContent,
  makeStyles,
  Typography,
  Divider,
  DialogActions,
  Button,
  Grid,
  Box
} from "@material-ui/core";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  dialogWrapper: {
    padding: theme.spacing(2),
    position: "absolute",
    top: theme.spacing(5)
  },
  dialogTitle: {
    paddingRight: 0
  },
  button: {
    margin: theme.spacing(0.5),
    textTransform: "none"
  },
  buttonsContainer: {
    display: "flex",
    flex: "0 0 auto",
    justifyContent: "flex-end",
    width: "100%",
    height: "100%"
  },
  buttons: {
    display: "flex"
  }
}));

function Popup(props) {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const { title, children, openPopup, setOpenPopup, ...rest } = props;

  return (
    <Dialog
      {...rest}
      open={openPopup}
      maxWidth="sm"
      classes={{ paper: classes.dialogWrapper }}
    >
      <DialogTitle dividers="true" className={classes.dialogTitle}>
        <div style={{ display: "flex" }}>
          <Typography variant="h4" component="div" style={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
            Country
          </Typography>
        </div>
      </DialogTitle>
      <Divider />
      <DialogContent direction="row">{children}</DialogContent>
      <DialogActions>
        <Grid container className={classes.buttonsContainer}>
          <Box className={classes.buttons}>
            <Button
              className={classes.button}
              variant="contained"
              color="primary"
              type="submit"
              form="form"
            >
              Save
            </Button>
            <Button
              className={classes.button}
              color="default"
              fullWidth
              onClick={() => {
                setOpenPopup(false);
              }}
            >
              Cancel
            </Button>
          </Box>
        </Grid>
      </DialogActions>
    </Dialog>
  );
}

export default Popup;
```

[Print submiting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VwbgW.png)

I put the code in the Sandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-list-modal-form-qzn2b

I thank you for your help!

Comment: I'm not so familiar with reactJS but you need to add the attribute **disabled** on your button as soon is submited. **<Button disabled ... >add</button>**

Comment: "I need to disable the action buttons in modal while the form is submitting", why do you want to do that? Are you trying to prevent submitting twice maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of Wrapping the entire CountryForm with the Popup you can wrap the Form rendered via Formik with the Popup, doing this we will now be able to access the `isSubmitting` prop provided by Formik.

```
<Formik
      enableReinitialize={true}
      initialValues={initialValues}
      validationSchema={validationSchema}
      onSubmit={_onSubmit}
    >
      {({ errors, touched, isSubmitting }) => {
        return (
          <Popup
            openPopup={openPopup}
            setOpenPopup={setOpenPopup}
            disableSave={isSubmitting}
          >
            <Form id="form">
              <Grid container direction="row">
                <Grid className={classes.itemGrid} item xs={12}>
                  <Field
                    name="abbreviation"
                    label="Abbreviation"
                    margin="dense"
                    variant="outlined"
                    disabled={isSubmitting}
                    component={TextField}
                  />
                </Grid>
                <Grid className={classes.itemGrid} item xs={12}>
                  <Field
                    name="name"
                    type="text"
                    fullWidth
                    label="Name"
                    margin="dense"
                    variant="outlined"
                    disabled={isSubmitting}
                    component={TextField}
                  />
                </Grid>
              </Grid>
            </Form>
          </Popup>
        );
      }}
    </Formik>
```

[Working Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-list-modal-form-forked-7brmr?file=/src/pages/Country/CountryForm.js)

Comment: I can't believe it was that simple!!!
Thank you very much!!
Hugs from Brazil!